# Rayclass group and Hilbert class group, $\mathrm{Gal}(K(\mathfrak{a})/K)\cong(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{a})^\times$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field with class number $1$. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal of $ \mathcal{O}_K$ and $K(\mathfrak{a})$ denote the ray class field of $K$ modulo $\mathfrak{a}$.

Why does $\mathrm{Gal}(K(\mathfrak{a})/K)\cong(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{a})^\times$ hold?

Related question ; Answer of [CM Elliptic Curves and a result concerning ray class fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266107/cm-elliptic-curves-and-a-result-concerning-ray-class-fields?rq=1) reads class field theory describes difference between Hilbert class field and ray class group, but I don't see what kind of proposition he uses.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is all pretty "standard", you should be able to find these staments in several places. For example, have a look at chapter 5.3 of https://www.math.mcgill.ca/~darmon/courses/18-19/cft/refs/milne.pdf

Comment: The claim in the question is actually false as stated. You need to take the quotient of $(O_K / \mathfrak{a})^\times$ by the image of the global units $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$.